# Trying to identify a Eco-disaster/apocalyptic novel I read in the 80’s

Tags: story-identification, novel, apocalypse

Trying to find a eco-disaster novel I read in the mid-80’s. Believe it was a new release at the time.

- World was being consumed in a wave of disaster and mutated creatures due to pollution/waste
- Believe the story focus was a group of scientists trying to fight and then flee the incoming apocalypse
- Survivors escape to space stations at the end of the novel. Remember a scene where kids would swim with fish in zero G
- Remember that one of the mutations were giant white grubs worms. Also someone was killed by a giant spider nesting in a sit-down arcade cabinet

Would love to read this story again, if it can be identified. Thanks in advance.